# VB6 application leaks memory on Server 2008 but not in Windows 7

Tags: vb6, oledb, activereports

For some reason that regretfully went under my radar (suspecting Windows Update) a VB6 reporting client now leaks memory on Server 2008. It uses active reports and OLE DB.

It works perfectly on Windows 7 machines. The  target deployment is Citrix XenApp on Windows Server 2008, and here the app is very slow and consumes large amounts of memory (GBs when it's usually MBs). This happens just after the app gets a big resultset from the OLEDB provider. This issue happens both when compiling with and without optimization.

Are there any good tools to find out what's wrong or which call/component is the one leaking memory, or any other things one should try?

Comment: Using [SysInternal's VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) will show you what type of memory, and possibly the (string) contents. It can also profile the process to show you the call stack where it's allocated.

Comment: Citrix Memory Optimization disabled?

Comment: we've found our issues using the tools of redgate. i think it was memory profiler. one of our services used to leak by creating strings in logs :)

Comment: Why do you think that it is leaking memory? I hope you are not using the Task Manager.

Comment: @CodyGray It crashes  with an out of memory error eventually. And the program immediately consumes about 1 GB of memory according to VMMap. On Windows 7 it never uses more than 20 MB of ram.

Answer (score 0):

try to add some flags into your code where you can incrementally turn on/off parts of the process.  for example, if (debug == 1) get the recordset and stop without running the report.    if (debug==2) get the recordset and execute the report without printing or viewing (just report.Run then set to Nothing.  and so on.   If you have sub-reports or images see if you can remove them temporarily.     There are some tools that can track memory leaks but I am not sure if they are still available for VB6 one of them is BoundsChecker.